# An upper bound for derivative of holomorphic function at zero

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f \in \mathbb{H}(\mathbb{D})$(I mean$f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{D})$ be such that $\forall z \in \mathbb{D},  Re f(z) > 0$ and $f(0) = a > 0$. Prove that:
$|f'(0)| \leq 2a$.

I tried to solve it with Cauchy integral formula but I can't. Is there a solution with this method?

It's the problem 1.14 in "A Course in Complex Analysis and Riemann Surfaces(Wilhelm Schlag)".

Comment: Map, with a conformal $g$, the [upper half plane to the unit disc](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705000/conformal-maps-from-the-upper-half-plane-to-the-unit-disc-has-the-form) in such a way that $a$ maps to $0$. In the link, you would take $\beta=a$. Then use [Schwarz's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma) with $g(f(z))$.

Comment: Consider a holomorphic function $\phi:H^+\to \Bbb D$ and consider the composition $\phi\circ f$ and then apply problem 1.12, where $H^+$ is the open upper half-plane.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1684925